# If a, b ∈ Z are coprime show that 2a + 3b and 3a + 5b are coprime.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

If $a, b \in \mathbb{Z}$ are coprime show that $2a + 3b$ and $3a + 5b$ are coprime.

My normal approach seems to get me nowhere.

Comment: what might your normal approach be? share them here and perhaps we can help point out where you'd gone wrong?

Comment: If $an + bm = 1$, can you find $N$ and $M$ such that $(2a+3b)N + (3a + 5b)M  = 1$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If integer $d$ divides $2a+3b,3a+5b$

$d$ must divide $-3(2a+3b)+2(3a+5b)=b$

$d$ must divide $5(2a+3b)-3(3a+5b)=a$

$d$ must divide $(a,b)$

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\GL}{\mathrm{GL}}$$\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}$More generally, if the integer matrix
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
s & t\\
u & v\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
has determinant $\pm 1$, then the pair $\begin{bmatrix}c& d\end{bmatrix}$ given by
$$
\begin{bmatrix}c & d\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}a & b\end{bmatrix}
\cdot
\begin{bmatrix}
s & t\\
u & v\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
will be coprime iff $\begin{bmatrix}a & b\end{bmatrix}$ is.

The reason is that $\begin{bmatrix}a & b\end{bmatrix}$ is coprime if and only if there is $g \in \GL(2, \Z)$ such that $\begin{bmatrix}a & b\end{bmatrix} g = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$.

Answer (score 1):

More generally, if $u=2a + 3b$ and $v=3a + 5b$ , then $\gcd(u,v)=\gcd(a,b)$.

Indeed, from
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
u \\ v
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 3\\
3& 5 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
a \\ b
\end{bmatrix}
$$
by inverting the matrix we get
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
a \\ b
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
\hphantom- 5 & -3\\
-3& \hphantom- 2 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
u \\ v
\end{bmatrix}
$$
These two equations imply that $d$ divides $u,v$ iff $d$ divides $a,b$.

In algebra terms, the two equations imply that $\{a,b\}$ and $\{u,v\}$ generate the same subgroup of $\mathbb Z$. It's well known that $\langle x,y \rangle = \gcd(x,y)\mathbb Z$, hence the result.