# Proof of the Greatest Denominator

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Can someone help me prove this. It is a proof of the sum and difference of the greatest common denominator.

**Given**: x and y are integers with a GCD of 1.

**Prove**: that the GCD of x + y and x − y is either 1 or 2.

Comment: Follow : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1105240/if-a-b-%E2%88%88-z-are-coprime-show-that-2a-3b-and-3a-5b-are-coprime

Comment: @labbhattacharjee I'm not quite understanding how that relates to my problem.

Comment: Have you followed my answer , there ?

Comment: It seems you are talking about the greatest common *divisor.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\gcd(a+b,a-b)=\gcd(a+b, a+b+a-b)=\gcd(a+b,2a)$ which divides $2a$, but any divisor of $a$ does not divide $b$, so it divides $2$, so it is equal (modulo multiplication by $\pm 1$) to $1$ or $2$.

Comment: I may not understand what you intend by *proof*, but *that* is a proof in my understanding of what a proof is.

Answer (score 0):

Since $\mathbf{GCD}(x,y)=1$ these two $\Bbb Z$ are coprime.

$$\gcd(x+y,x-y)=\gcd(x+y, x+y+x-y)=\gcd(x+y,2x)$$

This divides $2x$, and since any divisor of $x$ does not divide $y$, it must be that it divides $2\implies$ it is either $1$ or $2$

Comment: Sorry @Robert, your answer beat mine by miles