# Prove/Disprove: If a, b ∈ Z (with at least one not zero) and d = gcd(a, b) then d = gcd(a + b, a − b).

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics

I believe this statement is true, but I've only tried one set of numbers (a = 8, b = 12). How would I go about proving this?

Comment: try two odd numbers.

Comment: Used a = 35, b = 25. gcd(35,25) = 5, but gcd (60, 10) = 10. So looks like this statement is actually false. Thank you!

Comment: You can, however, show that if $d=(a,b)$ then $(a+b,a-b)$ is either $d$ or $2d$.

Comment: Simpler: $a=b=1$

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1445882/589.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to prove lulu's comment, which is actually quite useful.

$\gcd(a+b,a-b) = \gcd((a+b)+(a-b),a+b) = \gcd(2a,a+b)$

${} \mid \gcd(2,a+b) \gcd(a,a+b) \mid 2 \gcd(a,b)$.