# Greatest Common Divisor of a+b,a-b

Tags: arithmetic, gcd-and-lcm

Prove that $gcd(a + b, a − b) ≥ gcd(a, b)$

Let $d=gcd(a+b,a-b)$
So $d=m(a+b)+n(a-b) = a(m+n)+b(m-n)$
Which implies $d|a$ and $d|b$
Therefore, $d|gcd(a,b)$
$gcd(a,b)=dx ≥ d= gcd(a + b, a − b)$

Why am I getting the opposite inequality?

Comment: "Which implies $d|a$ and $d|b$" This is wrong.

Comment: $d=a(m+n)+b(m-n)$ does not imply $d\mid a,b$.

Comment: Actually, $\gcd(a, b) \le \gcd(a + b, a − b) \le 2\gcd(a, b)$. See http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1445882/589.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\gcd(a,b)\mid a,b\implies \gcd(a,b)\mid a+b,a-b$$

$$\iff \gcd(a,b)\mid \gcd(a+b,a-b)\implies \gcd(a,b)\le \gcd(a+b,a-b)$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $g=\gcd(a,b)$. Then
$$
\begin{align}
\gcd(a+b,a-b)
&=g\gcd\left(\frac{a+b}g,\frac{a-c}g\right)\\
&\ge g
\end{align}
$$
since
$$
\gcd\left(\frac{a+b}g,\frac{a-c}g\right)\ge1
$$