# Let $a$ and $b$ be relatively prime integers. Find all possible values of $\gcd(a+2b,a-2b)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

My attempt: it is known that $(a,b)=1$. Let $d = (a+2b,a-2b)$.

Then it follows that $d|{(a+2b)}$ and $d|{(a-2b)}$, and thus $d|{(m(a+2b)+n(a-2b))}$; that is, $d$ divides all linear combinations of $(a+2b)$ and $(a-2b)$.

If we write $X = a + 2b$ and $Y = a - 2b$, then:

- $2X+2Y=4a$ and thus $d|4a$
- $X-Y=4b$ and thus $d|4b$

Therefore $(4a,4b)=d$ and $(4a,4b)=4(a,b)=4$.

It follows that $(a+2b,a-2b) \leq 4$ and so 4,3,2, and 1 are possible values.

$(a+2b,a-2b) \neq 3$ given it is not a divisor of 4.

Therefore $(a+2b,a-2b) = \{4,2,1\}$

As one could imagine I'm posting because I am not sure of my proof. In particular I'm not certain whether the less than or equal to 4 actually follows from the previous line. As well as this, I'm not really certain my explanation for 3 not being in the answer set is adequate.

Comment: Do either of the questions cited actually address this question? In the first, $ad-bc=-4$. In the second, $\gcd(a,b)\mid2$

Comment: @robjohn It's an abstract dupe of the general answers there (viz. determinant = $4$). If I overlooked something then please do elaborate.

Comment: @BillDubuque: *abstract duplicate*? I'm not sure exactly what that means, but I don't see an answer to those questions that, without a fair amount of extra work, answers this question. Sure, there are starting points and hints, but no answers. I might even go further and show that $$ (a+2b,a-2b)=\left\{\begin{array}{} 2&\text{if }a\equiv0\pmod4\\ 1&\text{if }a\equiv1\pmod4\\ 4&\text{if }a\equiv2\pmod4\\ 1&\text{if }a\equiv3\pmod4\\ \end{array}\right. $$

Comment: @robjohn Various linked answers show (generally) how to rigorously deduce that the gcd  $\,d\mid 4,\,$ which answers both of the *specific* questions asked in the final paragraph. What remains is very easy, viz. to show that the values $\,d = 1,2,4\,$ actually do occur, but this is not what was explicitly asked about (and is  probably also a dupe given that we likely have hundreds of such problems by now).

Comment: @Andrew $\,d\mid na,nb\iff d\mid (na,nb) = n(a,b) = n\ $ follows by the [GCD Universal Property](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3356075/d-mid-a-b-iff-d-mid-gcda-b-gcd-universal-property/3356212?r=SearchResults&s=1|120.8461#3356212) and [GCD Distributive Law](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/705874/242). These are *fundamental* GCD laws that one should master as early as possible in order to become proficient at number theory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything before "Therefore $(4a, 4b) = d$" looks good.

From $d\mid 4a$ and $d\mid 4b$, you do not know that $(4a, 4b) = d$. You only know that $d\mid (4a, 4b)$, which is to say, $d\mid 4$.

With that result, we can rule out every possibility except $d = 1, 2$ or $4$. However, we do not yet know which of those three values are actually possible.

In this case, I think the best option is to actually check. If $a = 6, b = 1$, then we get $d = 4$. If $a = 5, b = 1$, we get $d = 1$. Finally, if $a = 4, b = 1$, we get $d = 2$. So they are indeed all possible.

Comment: That definitely makes sense, I felt like I was making too large of a jump with that step. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a different take:

Let $u=a+2b$ and $v=a-2b$. Then
$$
\pmatrix{ u \\ v}
=
\pmatrix{ 1 & \hphantom-2 \\ 1 & -2}
\pmatrix{ a \\ b}
$$
The matrix above has determinant $-4$ and so, by Cramer's rule, $4 (a \mathbb Z + b \mathbb Z) \subseteq u\mathbb Z + v \mathbb Z$.

We have $a \mathbb Z + b \mathbb Z = \mathbb Z$ because $\gcd(a,b)=1$.
We also have $u\mathbb Z + v \mathbb Z = d \mathbb Z$, where $d=\gcd(u,v)$.

Therefore, $4 \mathbb Z \subseteq d \mathbb Z$ and so $d$ divides $4$, that is, $d \in \{1,2,4\}$.

We still need to show that all possible values of $d$ actually occur:

- $a=1, b=0$ gives $d=1$
- $a=0, b=1$ gives $d=2$
- $a=2, b=1$ gives $d=4$

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1445882/589